# Joomla 3.4.5 to 3.4.6 Simple?

Tags: joomla-3.4

I've never worked with this version of Joomla but am led to beleive that it is pretty simple to upgrade to 3.4.6 from 3.4.5 - having done a few upgrades on the older versions I am skeptical!

Anyone tried it and if so did you find it simple enough?

I will be backing up the database and code beforehand of course but want a rough idea of the timescales involved.

Comment: Thanks guys, yes it was simple and painless!  Pity I can't give you both accepted answer status but you have my sincere thanks!

Comment: 3.4.6 to 3.4.8 just done today, that was also painless!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updating from Joomla 3.4.5 to 3.4.6 is a simple one-click update. Unless you have core hacks (not recommended), the update process is absolutely safe. But please update, because this fixes a critical security issue.

Here's from the [Joomla Release News](https://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5641-joomla-3-4-6-released.html):

> What's in 3.4.6
>
> Version 3.4.6 is released to address four reported security
>   vulnerabilities and includes security hardening of the user password
>   reset system. Security Issues Fixed
>
> High Priority - Core - Remote Code Execution (affecting Joomla 1.5 through 3.4.5)
>   Low Priority - Core - CRSF Hardening (affecting Joomla 3.2.0 through 3.4.5)
>   Low Priority - Core - Directory Traversal (affecting Joomla 3.2.0 through 3.4.5)
>   Low Priority - Core - Directory Traversal (affecting Joomla 3.4.0 through 3.4.5)

As for the time frame, I estimate 4-5 seconds (once you backed up your site...)

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is a very simply update which fixes a massive security vulnerability which has been about for years, so if you haven't already updated, I suggest you do so immediately using Joomla's 1 click update feature